# Regge symmetry and outer automorphisms of Dynkin diagrams

Tags: representation-theory, mathematical-physics

Quantum $6j$-symbols are the coefficients of the change of basis matrix in the central extension of Temperley-Lieb algebra(see [the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691036403) by Kauffman and Lins). It is my understanding that Ocneanu has interpreted them as being coefficients of matrices of maps between the path algebras on affine $E_6$ and regular, non-affine  $A_{11}$ (see [this](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104180144) paper by Roche.)

It seems reasonable to believe that the celebrated Regge symmetry of the $6j$-symbols should correspond to some automorphism of (affine) $E_6$ (mainly because it has already been shown to correspond to some automorphism of affine $F_4$ (see [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603398) paper by Boalch.)

Is anything known about such an interpretation, or does anyone have an idea how to go about proving such a statement?

Comment: Misread that as *reggae* symmetry at first and immediately thought of [this](http://cdn.themetapicture.com/media/funny-printer-Bob-Marley.jpg).

Comment: Interesting question, but I think its level is more appropriate for [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/).